# Python script is not producing any output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script where I'm trying to read all .txt files in a directory and determine if they return True or False for any conditions that are in my script. I don't get an error message but the script doesn't produce any output. I want the script to read in .txt files that contain text formatted in .json format. Then I want the script to determine if the .txt file matches any of the statements in my code below. I then want to output the result to a csv file. Your help is very much appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# regarding whether any positive results were found for the domain on VT.


import csv
import json
import pprint
import sys
import os


CSVPATH = 'CsvResults.csv'
VTOUTPUTPATH = './output/'
VTOUTPUTEXT = '.txt'
#files_to_search = [f for f in os.listdir('./output/') if f[-4:] == '.txt']
#vt_result_path = files_to_search
#vt_result = vt_result_check(vt_result_path)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)


# Check files from VirusTotal queries for any positive results
# Result is false unless any nonzero positive result is true
def vt_result_check(vt_result_path):
    vt_result = None
    try:
        vt_result = False
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as vt_result_file:
                vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)
            #vt_result_path = [f for f in os.listdir('./output/') if f[-4:] == '.txt']
            #vt_result = None
            #try:
            #    vt_result = False
            #    with open(infile) as vt_result_file:
            #        vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

            # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_referrer_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_communicating_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_downloaded_samples']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for any positive detected URLs
            try:
                for sample in (vt_data['detected_urls']):
                    if (sample['positives'] > 0):
                        vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
            try:
                if (vt_data['Dr.Web category'] == "known infection source"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "elevated exposure"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "phishing and other frauds"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
            try:
                if (vt_data['Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category'] == "suspicious content"):
                    vt_result = True
            except:
                pass

            #pp.pprint(vt_data)
    except:
        pass
    return vt_result



def cert_check(csvpath):
    with open(csvpath, 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['vt_result']
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['VirusTotal Results'])
        vt_result_path = VTOUTPUTPATH + subject_dom + VTOUTPUTEXT
        vt_result = vt_result_check(vt_result_file)
        writer.writerow([vt_result])
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Its hard for us to walk through a program because we'd have to make sample files with names- or read through the entire program and see if we can see the issue without running the code

Comment: The script does nothing but **defining** two functions. You should run them.

Comment: @KlausD. How do I get it working then? I would greatly appreciate your assistance?

Comment: @chevybow I've tried to do some debugging but I'm not getting any error message. Do you have any idea of what to do?

Comment: What's with all the useless `try/except: pass`? There's even one around the _entire body of the function_! You won't see any exceptions and just wonder what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually call the functions my dude

```
def my_func(stuff):
    print(stuff) #or whatever

my_func(1234)
```

Update per comment

```
import os
p=r'path\to\your\files' 

filelist=os.listdir(p) #creates list of all files/folders in this dir

#make a loop for each file in the dir
for file in filelist:
    f=os.path.join(p,file) #this just joins the file name and path for full file path
    your_func(f)  #here you can pass the full file name to your functions
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response! I got it to print out of the result for the first .txt file in the console but how do I get the loop to go through all of the files in the directory? I very much appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Sure, i updated my answer to show how to do that. Or at least one way to do that, there are probably lots

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, the immediate problem seems to be that you simply never call your `cert_check` function. However, while this site is actually not for codereview, I can't help but suggest some improvements to your code. In particular, all those `try/except:pass` constructs make it exceedingly hard to detect *any* errors in your code, as all exceptions will just silently be catched and swallowed by the `except: pass`.

- you should remove all those `try/except:pass` blocks, in particular the one surrounding the entire function body
- if some of the keys are non-existing, you can use `dict.get` instead of `[]`, which will not raise a key error but return `None` (or some default) instead, and all your checks will still work
- you can use `|=` instead of the `if` checks to `or` the result of the check to the variable
- you can use `any` to check whether any element in some list satifies some condition

My version of your `vt_result_check` function:

```
def vt_result_check(vt_result_path):
    vt_result = False
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

        # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
        # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
        # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
        # Look for any positive detected URLs
        sample_types = ('detected_referrer_samples', 'detected_communicating_samples',
                        'detected_downloaded_samples', 'detected_urls')
        vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types 
                                                 for sample in vt_data.get(sample_type, []))

        # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Dr.Web category') == "known infection source"

        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
        threats = ("elevated exposure", "phishing and other frauds", "suspicious content")
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category') in threats

    return vt_result
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tired running your script and I unfortunately got a couple error messages above invalid syntax at lines 17 and 22. I'm having trouble figuring out what the proper syntax is. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @bedford There was a mismatched parens in one line, but I can't find another syntax error. Does it work now, or do you get a runtime error? If so, which one?

Comment: Thank you for your response! If I setup dunder main and try to print out vt_result_check like this: 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(vt_result_check(path))

Then I get this error message:
line 33, in <module>
    print(vt_result_check(path))

Comment: Well, that's not inside the function, but the code _calling_ the function. What is `path`? In you original code, you used `vt_result_file`, which was not defined (but `vt_result_path` instead); maybe the problem is similar here?

Comment: I set the path as just path this type and I declared it at the top of my script.